# Java : access project directory outside src

Tags: java, url, nullpointerexception, resources, directory

I want to retrieve files from the folder `ressources/images/`,so I do this in my `Main.java` :

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../ressources/images/");
File folder = new File(url.getFile());

File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Here is the overall project hierarchy

```
   myGame
      - ressources
          -- images
              --- image1.jpg
              --- image2.jpg
              --- image3.jpg
      - src
          -- dvt
             --- Main.java
```

But I get this error at the 2nd line:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

So I assume it couldn't find the directory.

Using an absolute path works fine, but not the relative one:

```
    File folder = new File("D:\\courses\\UE4\\projet2\\ressources\\images\\");
```

Comment: Does your `resources` directory really have a double 's' in it?

Comment: Yes, it's in french :)

Comment: OK, just wanted to verify that it was not a typo.

Comment: @Takichiii The `ressources` directory is 2 levels upper than `Main.java`, not just one. Did you try with `.getResource("../../ressources/images/");`?

Comment: Why are you using relative paths at all?

Comment: @BackSlash Yes I tried it just forgot to change it here.
@cricket_007 I tried `File folder = new File("ressources/images/");`but doesn't work either, is `getResource()` only for files `src` folder?

Comment: @cricket_007 you're asking why i use relative paths, do you mean i could use an absolute path instead?

Comment: I mean you could try  "/resources" (or no slash). The real solution would be to print the classpath and see where the error is

Answer (score 1):

"ressources" is just a typo on your post, or the actual name of the folder?

Also, the formal structure is usually

```
  myGame
      - src
          -- main
            --- java
               ---- Main.java
          -- resources
            --- images
              ---- image1.jpg
              ---- image2.jpg
              ---- image3.jpg
```

The NPE you are getting is because url is null on line 2.

This works OK for me:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images");
File folder = new File(url.getFile());
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Comment: No, this is not a solution at all to my problem, I want to use the strict structure that I gave, changing the problem statement is not the way to solve it. Read the topic name : "access project directory outside src"

Comment: Sorry, I paid careful attention to your entire post but not the title. Je. We need a new angle at this. If you want to use getClassLoader(), we need to add your /ressources/ folder to the classpath manually, or use something different from getClassLoader()

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File("ressources/images");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

The folder "ressources" is placed at the same level than the applicaction so this should work. But you are using the java maven convention of placing sources at src/main/java and resources at src/main/resources but with different names and no build tool I guess. It is strange.

Comment: I tried this before(cf other comments) but didn't work. I am obligated to use this hierarchy strictly, it is not a Maven projet.

Comment: This solution works. Ive already tried it. But when running your game the ressources folder must be placed at the same level than the executable jar

Comment: No, this is not a solution at all to my problem, I want to use strictly the structure that I gave, which is having `ressources` outside `src`. changing the problem statement is not the way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ressources/images");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

System.getProperty("user.dir") is the project folder, in your case myGame
just append the remaning path and it will work